# Root test with nested power function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> I've got an infinite series that can be tested for convergence/divergence using the root test:
>   $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{k}{k + 1}\right)^{2k^2}$$

So, by taking the nth root as per the root test, one of the powers of 2k gets removed to leave us with the following:

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{k}{k + 1}\right)^{2k}$$

I have tried to let $y = A_k$ (where $A_k$ is the function $f$ in the series), and taking the $\ln$ of both sides then dividing the right side by $\frac 1{2k}$ instead of multiplying by $2k$ so that I can start L'Hopital's Rule, but as soon as I got into it I realized it would be a huge line of quotient rule derivatives resulting in $1$
That makes the test inconclusive. My textbook however does say that the series converges.

I'm pretty lost, am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your limit $L$, so that $\displaystyle L = \lim_{k \to \infty}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{2k}$. Then $\displaystyle \ln L = \lim_{k \to \infty}2k\ln\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)$. Using l'Hospital's rule, you can compute this limit to be $-2$. So we have $\ln L = -2$, or $L = \exp(-2)$.

Now, what does the Root Test tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Remember also that $\left(\frac{k+1}{k}\right)^k=\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k\to e^1$ as $k\to\infty$.

No logarithms, no l'Hopital needed.