# Can someone explain this answer for solving this limit: $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left (\frac n {n+1} \right )^{2n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left (\frac n {n+1}  \right )^{2n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left (\frac{n+1}{n} \right )^{-2n} =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left (1 + \frac 1n \right )^{-2n}= \left (\lim_{n\to\infty}\left (1 + \frac 1n \right )^{n}  \right )^{-2} = e^{-2}$$

What I don't understand is why is it a -2 and not +2? Also, is there a better way to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Because $-2 \cdot n = -2n$, but $+2 \cdot n = 2n$, and $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$.

Comment: Related: [same limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705982/root-test-with-nested-power-function).

Comment: @JohnHughes yes but why is it negative in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-1}$.  But, perhaps a better way to avoid any confusion is to write

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{2n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^2=\frac1{e^2}=e^{-2}$$

Comment: Thanks! but how/where did the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}\right)^2$ come from? I understand the denominator but why is there a 1 on top? Not quite understanding how that worked.

Comment: $$\frac{n}{n+1}=\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac1{1+\frac1n}$$

Comment: Thanks so much I get it now, it's all about using fraction rules. By putting 1 on top and flipping the fraction we aren't actually changing anything because we could just flip it right back to normal like:
$$\frac{1}{1}*\frac{n}{n+1}$$
And the 2 would be distributed back accordingly and would maintain the same function.
This is a lot easier to see now.

Comment: You're welcome!  Pleased to hear that you have it now!  -Mark

Comment: You got it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

$\lim (\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n} = \lim e^{\log(\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n}} = \lim e^{2n\log(\frac{n}{n+1})} = e^{\lim 2n\log(\frac{n}{n+1})}$.

$\lim 2n \log (\frac{n}{n+1}) = \lim \frac{\log (\frac{n}{n+1})}{\frac{1}{2n}} = \lim \frac{\frac{1}{\frac{n}{n+1}(n+2)^2}}{\frac{-1}{2n^2}} = \lim -2 \frac{n}{n+1} = -2(1) = -2.$

So, $\lim (\frac{n}{n+1})^{2n} = e^{-2}$.